# About Let's encrypt ACMEv1 deprecation. How to make certificate renewal work again in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, lets-encrypt

I'm running an old Ubuntu 14.04 server. It has been running without issues for years now but, with the recent deprecation of ACMEv1 i can't renew the certificates again. I have googled about how to deal with this problem but i'm not sure what to do.

In my server didn't make an "official installation" of letsencrypt. Rather, I just cloned it to some custom folder.

***My question is, can I just make a `git update` or clone letsencrypt again to a more recent version and expect everything to work just fine? Upgrading my server is NOT AN OPTION as of right now. About cloning, I suspect I could have problems with my old versions of python/pip as well, which is 2.7.6, and pip 1.5.4. Just trying to see what happens is not an option either. There are things that are not easy to recover from, so I prefer to have some kind of expert guidance before going all-in. The root of the problem is the deprecation of ACMEv1 though, so I wonder what is the least invasive way of solving that particular problem. `git update` or re-clone looks straightforward.***

The commit I cloned was the next one:

```sh
$ git log --name-status HEAD^..HEAD
commit 4c28fc417c978090ae8def91b81ed59f439e797a (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
Merge: b57371a3 0454031c
Author: bmw <bmw@users.noreply.github.com>
Date:   Tue Jan 5 18:02:19 2016 -0500

    Merge pull request #2073 from alex/more-typos
    
    Fixed a pair of typos in docstrings

commit 0454031cce4b88fef44e3e129e879a35b49c2314
Author: Alex Gaynor <alex.gaynor@gmail.com>
Date:   Sun Jan 3 14:37:08 2016 -0500

    Fixed a pair of typos in docstrings

M       acme/acme/jose/json_util.py
M       acme/acme/jose/util.py
```

so, yes, it's old.
Besides, I have some local changes, all created automatically by letsencrypt if I'm not wrong; I don't remember modifying any of those files:

```sh
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    typechange: acme/examples/standalone/localhost/cert.pem
    typechange: acme/examples/standalone/localhost/key.pem
    typechange: bootstrap/archlinux.sh
    typechange: bootstrap/centos.sh
    typechange: bootstrap/debian.sh
    typechange: bootstrap/fedora.sh
    typechange: bootstrap/gentoo.sh
    typechange: bootstrap/manjaro.sh
    typechange: bootstrap/suse.sh
    typechange: bootstrap/ubuntu.sh
    typechange: letsencrypt-apache/letsencrypt_apache/tests/testdata/debian_apache_2_4/default_vhost/apache2/conf-enabled/other-vhosts-access-log.conf
    typechange: letsencrypt-apache/letsencrypt_apache/tests/testdata/debian_apache_2_4/default_vhost/apache2/conf-enabled/security.conf
    typechange: letsencrypt-apache/letsencrypt_apache/tests/testdata/debian_apache_2_4/default_vhost/apache2/conf-enabled/serve-cgi-bin.conf
    typechange: letsencrypt-apache/letsencrypt_apache/tests/testdata/debian_apache_2_4/default_vhost/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
    typechange: letsencrypt-apache/letsencrypt_apache/tests/testdata/debian_apache_2_4/two_vhost_80/apache2/conf-enabled/other-vhosts-access-log.conf
    typechange: letsencrypt-apache/letsencrypt_apache/tests/testdata/debian_apache_2_4/two_vhost_80/apache2/conf-enabled/security.conf
    typechange: letsencrypt-apache/letsencrypt_apache/tests/testdata/debian_apache_2_4/two_vhost_80/apache2/conf-enabled/serve-cgi-bin.conf
    typechange: letsencrypt-apache/letsencrypt_apache/tests/testdata/debian_apache_2_4/two_vhost_80/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
    typechange: letsencrypt-apache/letsencrypt_apache/tests/testdata/debian_apache_2_4/two_vhost_80/apache2/sites-enabled/encryption-example.conf
    typechange: letsencrypt-apache/letsencrypt_apache/tests/testdata/debian_apache_2_4/two_vhost_80/apache2/sites-enabled/letsencrypt.conf
    typechange: letsencrypt-apache/letsencrypt_apache/tests/testdata/debian_apache_2_4/two_vhost_80/apache2/sites-enabled/mod_macro-example.conf
    typechange: letsencrypt-nginx/letsencrypt_nginx/tests/testdata/etc_nginx/ubuntu_nginx_1_4_6/default_vhost/nginx/sites-enabled/default
    typechange: letshelp-letsencrypt/letshelp_letsencrypt/testdata/mods-enabled/ssl.load

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    letsencrypt.zip

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Lastly, I renew the certificates with a script with the following format:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

sudo /.../my-letsencrypt-clone/letsencrypt-auto certonly -v -t --webroot \
   -w /var/www/web1/ -d www.domain1.com -d domain1.com -d subdomain.domain1.com \
   -w /var/www/web2/ -d web2 \
   -w /var/www/web3/ -d www.web3.com -d web3.com

last_cert=$(sudo find /etc/letsencrypt/live/ -type d -iname "www.domain1.com-*" | sort | tail -n 1)
sudo ln -sfn "$last_cert" /etc/ssl/private/domain1.com

sudo service apache2 restart
sudo service postfix restart
sudo doveadm reload
```

As you can deduce from the script, the certificate is shared by my apache2, postfix and doveadm services and no one else.

In my `/etc/letsencrypt/live` folder I have the following contents:

```sh
total 28
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 10  2017 www.domain1.com
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun 12  2017 www.domain1.com-0001
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun 12  2017 www.domain1.com-0002
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 30  2018 www.domain1.com-0003
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct 11  2018 www.domain1.com-0004
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun 13  2019 www.domain1.com-0005
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar  8 20:19 www.domain1.com-0006
```

So the script picks (`last_cert` variable) the folder with highest number, which is the one where letsencrypt is renewing certificates, and make `/etc/ssl/private/domain1.com` point to it, because that's the folder that my services are using to load the multidomain certificate.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 is past end of life. Upgrade to a supported Ubuntu release.

Answer (score 1):

Switch to a different client with fewer dependencies. I would suggest for instance [acme.sh](https://github.com/acmesh-official/acme.sh), which depends *primarily* on curl. I've not tested, but I see no reason it wouldn't run on 14.04.

And start moving away from 14.04. It probably doesn't support things such as TLS1.3, and your software issues will not become smaller in the next few years. Running a public facing server on 14.04 is probably not a great idea at this point.